# Google Earth Pro Automated Import and File Save

Tags: google-maps, google-earth

Via a script I write a single set of lat/long position information into a CSV file which updates meaningfully for me every 2-3 minutes.  I can of course successfully import that file into GE Pro and drop a placemark on the map.  Once having done that, I wish to save the map as a JPG.  No issues with the manual "version" of what I need to do...

How can I automate the import of the CSV file and automate the saving of the resultant map as well?  Each map will overwrite itself  (can have same file name).   I don't see where google has any command line interface to do something like this...

The final result will be, again, a map with the latest positioned placemark whenever I happen to access the jpg file.

Thank you

(I am aware of the Google Earth Fusion product.   Am hoping not to have to go that route as my need is fairly simple, I think)